# How to get data in descending order from database in asp.net core

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

I have a controller which gets data from **Batch** table. I want to get data in descending order. But I don't know where should I use **OrderByDescending()** in my case.

> My controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string sid)
    {
        var student = await _context.Student
            .Include(stu => stu.Registration)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(cat => cat.Registration.RegistrationId == sid);

        var batchList = await _context.Batch.ToListAsync();
        foreach (var batch in batchList)
        {
            student.Batches.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = batch.BatchId,
                Text = batch.BatchName
            });
        }

        return View(student);
    }
```

It would be great if anyone helps me

Comment: `_context.Batch.OrderByDescending(...)` ?

Comment: I've tried await _context.Batch.OrderByDescending(ToListAsync());
But its its getting error.

Comment: The statement is: `_context.Batch.OrderByDescending(b => b.BatchName).ToListAsync();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement is:

```
await _context.Batch.OrderByDescending(b => b.BatchName).ToListAsync();
```